# Web Deployment Projects tool in VS 2008

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, assemblies

When we install Web Deployment Projects tool, we also have an option to use it inside VS 2008. By selecting Property Pages we are presented with several options for configuring compilation options.One of Property Pages dialog boxed is named Output Assemblies. It presents us with the following options:

*** Merge all outputs to single assembly**

I assume this option doesn’t compile tag files?!

*** Merge all pages and control outputs to a single assembly**

Now how does this option differ from *Merge all outputs to single assembly*?At first I thought this option also pre-compiles tag files, but then why would output also contain aspx files, if they are already pre-compiled?!

*** Create a separate assembly for each page and control output**

I thought this option also compiled aspx pages, but then why would would output also contain aspx files, if they were already pre-compiled?!

thanx

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking for advice? An explanation of the options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a front-end to the aspnet_merge tool with different switches, [the MSDN doc explains the options and what they do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397866.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Here's very good tutorial on **[Web Deployment Projects](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx)** from Scott Gu's blog. It has great explanations on the options you describe and more. For Example:
[image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://www.scottgu.com/BlogPosts/deployment/step5.png))</sub>
The default option is to merge the entire web-site into a single assembly that you can name however you want.  This merges the output of all page/control compilation, app_code, and web-services into a single assembly (leaving one file to deploy).

There are other options you can choose as well for more granular control over the assembly generation.  For example, the second option above lets you compile each folder in your website into a separate named assembly (for example: MyCompany.MyWebApp.Folder1, MyCompany.MyWebApp.Folder2).  This is useful for patching large applications where you want to make a tactical update to just a portion of the site.

If you have an AssemblyInfo.cs/.vb class in your app_code directory, the deployment project will use the meta-data it contains to version the produced assemblies.  Alternatively, you can also set the version information specifically in the IDE.  This in turn saves it as an MSBuild variable in your project file.  You could optionally use a custom MSbuild task to set this variable dynamically at build-time (for example: to use a policy like we do at Microsoft where the build number is based on the current date).